# understanding ios stack trace [__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]

Tags: ios

I'm writing an iOS app and experiencing odd behavior with the app. It usually operates without error but the app is designed to be left open on an iPad for multiple days. After several days or so of use, it will seem to be unable to open and crash upon opening. If I re-download the app then it will open fine and not crash.

Here is an excerpt from the stack trace of a typical crash. It seems like there might be an issue with array insertion somewhere in the app, but how can I go about debugging this issue?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x26cbb5a2 __exceptionPreprocess + 122
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34cc2c72 objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x26bd6cb4 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 616
3   InstaAid                        0x00074b76 0x69000 + 47990
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x3522dc7e _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 6
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x3522dc6a _dispatch_client_callout + 18
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x3523954e _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1318
7   CoreFoundation                  0x26c8188c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 4
8   CoreFoundation                  0x26c7ffac __CFRunLoopRun + 1508
9   CoreFoundation                  0x26bccb4c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
10  CoreFoundation                  0x26bcc95e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
11  GraphicsServices                0x2e1091a4 GSEventRunModal + 132
12  UIKit                           0x2a21ec8c UIApplicationMain + 1436
13  InstaAid                        0x00076b8c 0x69000 + 56204
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x3526baaa tlv_initializer + 2
```

Comment: Please symbolicate it.

Comment: Guessing index you are trying to insert at, is not available. Check your array bounds.

Comment: Another guessing: you are adding a `nil` object.